# converting selected spinner value to defined int variable : android

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have an android program in which there is a spinner. i am getting the selected spinner value. i am able to send it as json too.
The problem is i want to send 1 if option1 is selected , 2 if option two is selected and so on.
Is there a method the selected value is converted to int value of my choice before i send it as json ?
the code is

```
 public void addItemsOnSpinner1() {

            s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Casual");
            list.add("Earned");
            list.add("Compensatory");
            list.add("Without Pay");
            list.add("Sick Leave");



            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()


            {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)
                       {
//                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s5.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                        final String SelectedLeave = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        balanceLeavesLeft();                           
                       }
                  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                        {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                        }
            });


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 3rd param is the position of selected item of your spinner:
It's arg2 in your code

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)
                       {
//                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s5.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                        final String SelectedLeave = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        balanceLeavesLeft();                           
                       }
```

--> So you just need print out: (arg2+1)

Comment: can u please explain how m new to android

Comment: arg2 = 0 when option1 is selected. arg2 = 1 when option 2 is selected.arg2 = 2 when option 3 is selected and so on.... 
So you only need : int selected = arg2 +1;

Answer (score 0):

tauitdnmd, answer is good but, the best way should be that you have an Entity class Opion as example and you have the string value for it and the int value of the selected row :) that's how is done usually.

```
public class YourOptionClass {

 private String optionName;
 private int optionValue;

 //construktor
 //getter and setter
 //to string

}
```

And you populate your spinner with this class.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3){

int option = YourAdapterClass.getItem(pos).getOptionValue();

}
```